# Dockerfile overwriting file in container

Tags: docker

I know this is written sloppy but I'm new to Docker and just trying to get the hang of it. I'm pulling an image `FROM wordpress:4.9.2-php7.2-apache`
Im then attempting to overwrite the `deflate.conf` file from inside my Dockerfile. The command I'm using is as follows.

```
ADD /deflate.conf ../../../etc/apache2/mods-available/
```

Using this command the image builds properly but as soon as I run it the container immediately fails?

When I comment out the ADD line, and `build/run` the image the container runs fine. So I attempted the copy command from the command line like so:

```
docker cp deflate.conf <name>:../../../etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf
```

Using this command everything is fine, and I get the desired result.

Im not sure why my Dockerfile won't work but the command line does. 
Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can post the logs of failed container. U can use docker logs  "container id " to get logs

Comment: im running docker ps -a to get the id of the failed container but when I run docker logs "id" it says "Invalid command '\xc2\xa0', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

Comment: Looks like bad characters in your deflate.conf. _Pure_ guess, maybe `docker cp` is modifying the encoding / something else, maybe even some implementation detail of underlying go libraries it uses, but `COPY` / `ADD` is exactly the copying the file, leading to one working and the other not. My advice would be to copy the contents of the file to the clipboard, then paste it back in as plain text, or switch on extra characters / encoding in your text editor.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the feedback. If that was the case though wouldn't the cp command from the command line not work as well?

Comment: Like I suggested above, it's not the same code doing both things. It could be an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use COPY or ADD with the absolute path. Instead of using `../../../etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf`, the format should be:

```
COPY /deflate.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf
```

You can also use Docker volumes for this. Ignore the COPY during `docker build`, then with your `run` [command](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Docker+CLI+Commands), include `-v` option:

```
$ docker run -v  /deflate.conf:/etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf -d -p 80:80 test
```

This should also do the trick. Please note that the modules on `/etc/apache2/mods-available/` are not loaded by default when apache service starts, active modules should be copied to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think same result as the command line you can achieve with:

```
COPY /deflate.conf ../../../etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf
```

in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I thought that would work as well but when I use that command I build it and run it but the container immediately fails.     docker build -t test .  followed by docker run -d -p 80:80 test. and then I run docker ps and no container is running.

Answer (score 0):

From the Dockerfile [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy:%7E:text=be%20used%20instead.-,COPY,to%20send%20the%20context%20directory%20(and%20subdirectories)%20to%20the%20docker%20daemon.,-If):

> **COPY** obeys the following rules:
>
> The  path must be inside the context of the build;  **you cannot**
> **COPY ../something /something**,  because the first step of a docker
> build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the
> docker daemon.

the same goes for `ADD`:

> **ADD** obeys the following rules:
>
> The  path must be inside the context of the build; **you cannot ADD**
> **../something /something**, because the first step of a docker build is
> to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
> daemon.

so if you want to copy something from your local to the container using **dockerfile**, make sure that file is within the same directory or subdirectory of your **dockerfile**.

I am not sure what are you trying to do with this

`docker cp deflate.conf <name>:../../../etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf`,

from what I understand is that you want to copy `deflate.conf` into that path within your container, but why you use `../../..` before `/etc`, I mean you can copy into that path directly like this :

`docker cp deflate.conf <containerName>:/etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf`